# How can I prevent Doctrine from thinking a zip code starting with 0 is an octal?

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, fixtures

I'm working on a symfony project, and I've been through the tutorial but this is my first attempt with a project.  I'm using Doctrine as the ORM, and I have a table of addresses.  Here's part of my schema.yml:

```
Address:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: address
  <snip>
  postal_code:
    type: string(10)
    fixed: false
    unsigned: false
    primary: false
    notnull: false
    autoincrement: false
```

And here's an entry from my fixtures.yml file:

```
Address:
  Addr_1:
    <snip>
    postal_code:  01104
```

The problem is, when I load the data using 'symfony doctrine:data-load', the entry in the database is stored as '580'.  How can I prevent Doctrine from converting the zip code as an octal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

zip codes, like phone numbers aren't integers - they are strings
so I'm guessing (don't know Doctrine) that you put quotes around it